# How to debug procedures in Scheme

Tags: debugging, guile

For example lets say I have the following procedure

```
(define (delete-adjacent-duplicates lst)
  (fold-right (lambda (elem ret)
                (if (equal? elem (first ret))
                    ret
                    (cons elem ret)))
              (list (last lst))
              lst))
```

So when I run the above procedure like `(delete-adjacent-duplicates '(1 2 3 3 4 4 4 5))` I want to see how it executes at each step. Also I want to setup breakpoints at certain locations so that the breakpoint fires at those particular points How can I achieve that using GNU Scheme(which is what I am using)? I know Dr.Racket provides debug functionalities but I want to use it from **Guile**

In [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/docs/docs-1.8/guile-ref/Tracing.html), it suggests to use `trace` function in the `(ice-9 debug)` module. However, that function is deprecated and I don't how to use the newly suggested module `(system vm trace)` module. Can anyone give a detailed example how I can debug procedures in Scheme?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to replace Scheme with Guile and remove the scheme tag? Debugging is implementation dependent so there will be no one solution for one language.

Comment: You right. I removed the scheme tag

Comment: @avidProgrammer AFAIK breakpoints only works at the REPL.

Comment: @amirouche Can you add an answer showing how to use breakpoints in REPL?

Comment: I don't know how to use them.